# Custom list with Word Javascript API

Tags: office-js

I would like to create my own style of list as it's possible in Word with this tool

[image]

For now, I use the `setListNumbering` method, and I specify this way the format of my list `list.setLevelNumbering(0,'Arabic',["[000",0,"]"])`. The problem is when I go to 10 or more elements, the '000' that is placed before the number of my list will never remove any zero to fit with a 4 length number. In Word it's possible to choose between, `1, 2, 3, ...`, `01, 02, 03, ...`, `001, 002, 003, ...`, ...

So my question is to know if it's possible to specify more precisely than 'Arabic', 'LowerLetter', ... the type of our list numbering.

**EDIT**

What I got when I have more than 9 elements

[image]

And what I want

[image]

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what happens when you have 10 or more elements?

Comment: @RickKirkham screenshot added